# Variable vertical gaps in Visualforce radio buttons

Tags: visualforce, css

**Goal**:

Make this radio button:

```
o Choice 1
o Choice 2
o Choice 3
o Choice 4
o Choice 5
```

Look like this (*note gaps*)

```
o Choice 1
o Choice 2

o Choice 3

o Choice 4
o Choice 5
```

**Given radio button VF markup is:**

```
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputText value="Choices"/>
        <apex:actionRegion >
            <apex:selectRadio id="choicesSelections" 
                              value="{!selectedChoice}"  
                              layout="pageDirection">
               <apex:selectOptions value="{!choices}"/>
               <apex:actionSupport reRender="theForm" event="onchange"/>
            </apex:selectRadio>
        </apex:actionRegion>
   </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

**Given VF controller includes**

```
public SelectOption[] choices {
    get {return new List<SelectOption> {
      new SelectOption('Choice 1','Choice 1'),
      new SelectOption('Choice 2','Choice 2'),
      new SelectOption('Choice 3','Choice 3'),
      new SelectOption('Choice 4','Choice 4'),
      new SelectOption('Choice 5','Choice 5')
    } private set; 
}
public String selectedChoice {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pretty obviously calls for a CSS approach but stackoverflow was only partially helpful as stackoverflow radiobutton examples didn't mimic the way Visualforce renders an `apex:selectRadio` component.

Using Chrome Developer Tools (or Firebug), one inspects the generated HTML and then one can manipulate using CSS styling.

The generated HTML looks like this (radio buttons are table rows):

```
<table role="presentation"
       id="MyVFPage:theForm:options:j_id43:j_id44:choiceSelections">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <input type="radio" ... value="Choice 1" .../>
     </td>
   </tr>
   ... tr-td-input for the other choices 2 - 5
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I used jQuery descendent selectors to manipulate the DOM on page load and on the completion of my spinner dialog.

```
<!-- first be sure the table can allow for adjustment -->
$j("[id$='choiceSelections']").css("border-collapse","separate");

<!-- Then add padding at the end of the 2nd and 3rd choices. 
     CSS nth-child starts counting at 1-->
$j("[id$='choiceSelections'] tr:nth-child(2) td").css("padding-bottom","2em")

$j("[id$='choiceSelections'] tr:nth-child(3) td").css("padding-bottom","2em");
```

*I'm sure CSS whizzes can probably come up with more efficient CSS selectors so feel free to comment*